# Distributing a hsqldb database for use

Tags: hsqldb

I have gone through the docs and I haven't been able to fully understand them.

My question :
For testing purpose we created a replica of a database in hsqldb and would want to use this as inprocess db for unit testing.
Is there a way that I can distribute the replica database so that people connect to this db.I have used the backup command and have the tar file.But how do I open a connection to the db which takes this backed up db... something on the lines of handing a .mdb file in case of Access to another user and asking him/her to use that.

Regards,
Chetan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand the backed up database using standard gzip / unzip tools, before you can connect to it.

The HSQLDB Jar can be used to extract the database files from the backup file. For example:

```
java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.lib.tar.DbBackup --extract tardir/backup.tar dbdir
```

In the example, the first file path is the backup file, and the second one, dbdir, is the directory path where the database files are expanded.